# Overcharge a sealed 12V lead-silver-calcium battery with a power supply to prevent sulphatation

Tags: battery-charging, 12v, lead-acid

I read that lead silver calcium battery need 14.8 V to fully charge. The max with my charger (ctek) is AGM setting which is 14.7 Volt. I fear this lower voltage this will lead to sulphatation of the battery

I have a regulated powersupply which can go up to 30V and 10A and it will deliver amps to the battery when I set it at 14.8V. I can hear the bubbling from the battery

I understand that these sealed batteries undergo a process where the hydrogen gas produced is somehow recombined back to water, but how should I charge this battery to the max without excessive gassing and loss of water. Max voltage, how long time?

Comment: _"I read that lead silver calcium battery need 14.8 V to fully charge"_ - where did you read that?

Comment: Several places: http://www.necon.co.za/agcabatt.php?w=1676&h=1048#openModal

Comment: It says the gassing voltage is raised from 14.4V to 14.8V which is correct, but the conclusion that any voltage below that will cause sulfation is suspect. Which model ctek charger do you have?

Comment: DO NOT boil/outgas a battery.|| Full charge and sulphation point are different. Holding at or above 12.8v (maybe 12.6) will prevent sulphation. || Again: Do not outgas your battery !!!!

Answer (score 1):

The boiling of lead batteries actually is electrolysis, splitting water into oxygen and hydrogen.

In a sealed battery there is a catalyst that recombines the gases into water. You need to put energy (from your charger) into the splitting, so you are not charging the battery at that point.
The "boiling" is used to stir the electrolyte. This helps in reducing or preventing sulfation. The manufacturer of your battery knows which voltage needs to be applied, and for how long, to get the best results.

The boiling has another advantage. The battery has six cells in series. When charging, all cells are charged with an identical charge, but they may not have been discharged identically. The cells with the higher initial charge will start boiling earlier during charging and their charging effectively stops, allowing the lesser charged cells to catch up; the cells are being balanced.
Boiling is good, but don't exaggerate it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are doing everything correctly?
Is the battery old? Does it get really hot when charged normally with your ctek charger? Do you have any Current/Voltage graph for its charging?

Batteries dont charge just from pumping a voltage on them, they use contant current and constant voltage at some point every time they get charged using their normal charges. Using your power supply may damage the battery.

You dont want to use your power supply and make the battery blow up on your face.

I would suggest getting a proper charger. If the ctek charger is designed for this kind of battery, this means it charges it correctly. After many uses of a battery, the Vmax may start to drop, so you wont get all those 14.8V after many charge cycles.

After all, 0.1V for a 14.8V battery sounds (and it is) vary insignificant.

Batteries have chemicals in them, you cant expect them to be perfect and charge up to a certain voltage. Maybe if you let your battery for a while after charging it with your ctek, it will go up to 14.8V on its own (by cooling down lets say)